# how to setting ncurses size by lines

Tags: ncurses

I'm building a GO game with ncurses, in the game it is about 19 lines.
I want make ncurses adjust font size by size of the window to make it always display 19 lines.
How to do this in ncurses? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ncurses doesn't set the size of the terminal.  If the terminal has at least 19 lines, you can set the [**`LINES`** environment variable](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-LINES), to tell ncurses to use only the first 19 lines of the screen (but expect some clearing/printing outside that range, since that's not the intended use of the variable).

Comment: thanks.but It just use a block of terminal and font size is same as before. With another opinion, can I change terminal font size when open the process by some system setting which is not ncurses?and then I could init ncurses to make my terminal resize.

Comment: sure - call `endwin`, then call *whatever* to change the font size and then `refresh`.  But that *whatever* would be terminal-specific (and not a programming question any longer).

Comment: Yes, It should be another topic about how to adjust terminal font size in C. I have create a new post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49000659/4887726).it's enough for ncurses part.